# Description and logo at the very top of browser?

Tags: live-preview

All, After we switched from Wordpress to Craft our site description and logo at the very top of the browser tab have been disappeared as shown in the image. Could you please guide me how can I achieve this? [image]

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Site title** - This is set with HTML meta tags and not really anything to do with Craft specifically. It depends how you "switched" from wordpress to Craft. Inside your document head, you need to include a title tag, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Website title goes here</title>
</head>
<body>
```

You can set this automatically by doing the following:

```
<title>{{ entry.title }}</title>
```

**Favicon (logo)** - Upload your .ico file to the /public_html directory.